# I want different header logo on each page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am a beginner in WP. I want different logo in each page of word press site like for few page of the site i need different logo and different for other. i tried to use conditional statement but as i am beginner so my overall site crashes and have a blank screen. if there is some plugin that can achieve this kind of functionality it would be really a great help.

Can you guide me how to achieve it.

Here is my header.php code i tried to edit it but all in vain.

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>

    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/source/vendor/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <div id="page" class="hfeed site">

        <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home" class="site-branding">
         <!--Editing start from here and i am gona delete all other code from above span section-->

                    <?php $header_image = get_header_image(); ?>
                    <h1 class="site-title">
                        <?php if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $header_image ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" />
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <span><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></span>
                    </h1>
                    <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
                </a>

                <nav id="site-navigation" class="site-primary-navigation slide-left">
                    <a href="#" class="primary-menu-toggle"><i class="icon-cancel-circled"></i> <span><?php _e( 'Close', 'jobify' ); ?></span></a>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu-primary' ) ); ?>
                </nav>

                <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
                <a href="#" class="primary-menu-toggle in-header"><i class="icon-menu"></i></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </header><!-- #masthead -->

        <div id="main" class="site-main">
```

Thanks

Comment: don't debug in the dark: turn on error_reporting/display_errors so php can TELL you what the problem is. they should never be off on a devel system in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try using something like this.

if(is_page('Blog')){ // the parameter used here is the post_title
    echo '<img src="http://yourwebsite.com/path-to-your-image/blog-logo.png" />';
}elseif(is_page('home')){ // the parameter used here is the post slug
    echo '<img src="http://yourwebsite.com/path-to-your-image/home-logo.png" />';
}elseif(is_page('42')){ // the parameter used here is the post id
    echo '<img src="http://yourwebsite.com/path-to-your-image/other-logo.png" />';
}else{ // else display default logo
   $header_image = get_header_image();
}


You can get more info here: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the theme you are using, it's sometimes build-in feature!

I know **Arcade Basic** which has this custom header feature:
https://wordpress.org/themes/arcade-basic/

There are probably much more theme's which supports this feature by default, search on the 'featured-image-header' and 'flexible-header' tags on the Wordpress site to find more themes....

- https://wordpress.org/themes/tags/featured-image-header/
- https://wordpress.org/themes/tags/flexible-header/

And maybe 'custom-header' tag?

- https://wordpress.org/themes/tags/custom-header/

Finally, there are indeed a **lot of plugins**, like "[WP Header Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-header-images/)", more can be found here:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=header+image&sort=